# Pygame gfxdraw module change line weight

Tags: python, pygame

I'm attempting to use the pygame.gfxdraw module in order to draw arcs. This module suits me better than the traditional pygame.draw module as it only requires a center point rather than a surrounding rectangle. However, for graphical reasons, I would like to increase the line weight of the arc so it is greater than one pixel thick. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think this is supported in `gfxdraw` yet. You could define a new arc function as follows:

```py
def draw_arc(surface, col, x, y, r, start_angle, stop_angle, width=1):
    """Draw an arc given the centre and radius"""
    pygame.draw.arc(
        surface, col, (x - r, y - r, r * 2, r * 2), start_angle, stop_angle, width=width
    )
```

Note that this function uses radians and works anticlockwise. `gfxdraw` uses degrees and works clockwise.